# how to detect end of file for string inputs in C++

Tags: c++, string, input

```
//Stores the line
string line;
//create a vector where each element will be a new line
vector<string> v;
int counter = 0;

//While we havent reached the end of line
while (getline(cin, line) && !cin.eof())
 {
    //get the line and push it to a vector
    v.push_back(line);
    counter++;
 for(int i = 0; i <counter; i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<endl;
     }
 }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, how come if i input lets say:

```
Hello
World (end of file)
```

The output is only:

```
Hello
```

The World is not outputted it only outputs both Hello and World if I input

```
Hello
World
(end of file)
```

Sorry if this is a really simple question :/ but i can't figure this out

Comment: Just `while (getline(cin, line))` is sufficient. No need for extra checking `!cin.eof()`.

Comment: Just doing `while (std::getline(...))` is enough. The [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function returns the stream, which can be used as a [boolean expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which returns `false` when you have error or end of file.

Comment: you are describing the same situation: hello world (end of line)!

Comment: Oh sorry the format changed when I posted the question i'll fix that

Comment: @helloTHERE There's a preview window below your edit box.

Comment: As for your problem, I assume you mean "(end of file)" and not "(end of line)"? Then it might be a problem with the console program, that is discards buffered input when you press the end-of-file key sequence. Or are you pressing e.g. `CTRL-C` instead of `CTRL-Z` (in Windows console) or `CTRL-D` (in Linux/OSX terminal)? Can you please say what you mean by "(end of line)"?

Comment: You're right, I mean end of file and I press CTRL-D

Comment: Then it's most likely the terminal program or the shell that's discarding the line, and then there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: I would think `&& !cin.eof()` is messing it up. Just try removing that as per first comment.

Comment: A line is by definition terminated by a newline char. If your file has a line fragment at the end, you could still consider that a line, but keep one thing in mind: A proper line can be empty! So, a "proper" file has a line fragment with a zero-length string in this case, which is one more special case to handle by skipping empty lines at the end. Now, you would have another special case when writing, because the last newline can be elided unless the string before is empty. Those are too many special cases for me. Stick to the rule, the last character in a file is a newline.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a line that ends with EOF without end of line, this:

```
while (getline(cin, line) && !cin.eof())
```

will have a `getline` that returns "all ok", but since the `getline` got to the actual end of file, `cin.eof()` is also `true`, meaning that your loop will not process the LAST of your input.

Change the code so that it simply does:

```
while (getline(cin, line))
```

and all will be fine.

If you really care that you actually read the whole file, and `getline` didn't fail for some arbitrary other reason, then using something like this AFTER the loop may ensure that - but I find it rather hard to think of a case where this would happen...

```
if (!cin.eof()) 
{
    cout << "Enexpected: didn't reach end of file" << endl;
}
```